# How to search for array value and return key in an associative array

Tags: php, search

```
<?php Array (
[2] =>
 Array ( [0] => cheap [1] => computer [2] => three ) 
[6] =>
 Array ( [0] => laptop [1] => phone [2] => car )
 ) ?>
```

I'm looking for a while to search for "cheap" and get 2. Pointers appreciated.

Comment: What do you ****** tried? Sorry but, come on! We see questions like that every day for all day long. It's so hard to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)??

Comment: I knew it was likely to throw some people off but what i've tried is way off I thought putting the code here wasn't going to help my case anyhow.

Comment: @Chiko of course it will help. We here to help not to do it for you. Guys like you are lucky because there are people hungry for reputation that answers questions like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = Array ( [2] => Array ( [0] => cheap [1] => computer [2] => three ) 
               [6] => Array ( [0] => laptop [1] => phone [2] => car ) )

foreach($arr as $key=>$value){
   if(in_array("cheap", $value)){
      echo $key;
   }

}
```